# Core Data - iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I need to sync my Core Data with the multiple devices. I read the iCloud sync for the Core Data is deprecated. I also tried to backup the .sqlite file into the iCloud and am having issues while trying to restore the .sqlite file

1. What is the best way to sync the Core Data across the devices ?
2. Is it a good choice to use the Core Data sync withe the iCloud Kit
   as its deprecated ?
3. Is it a good practice to backup the entire .sqlite file ?

Comment: Look into [Ensembles](http://www.ensembles.io/).  There is an open source version. At no point when using Ensembles do you deal with the .sqlite file

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @AgRizzo, I will look into it.